# How does authorization and authentication work in Azure SQL server?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I see a couple of different options for access control in Azure SQL server. There is a panel on Azure called access control (IAM) where roles like contributor/reader can be assigned to users.
[image]

The second place is the SQL server security artifacts which can be viewed in SSMS. Understanding how one of these policies works is straightforward, but how do these two policies work in tandem?
[image]

Comment: When you say “work in tandem” what do you mean exactly? Also, why are you expecting necessarily these two separate pieces to be similar ? Anytime I spend a lot of time trying to solve a problem and I don’t get hints online that others are talking about the same problem, or encountering issues as wel, it’s typically an error with how I think about the problem. What type of problem are you specifically trying to solve? Why is the unification preventing you from progressing with using the tool?

Comment: I am trying to understand the hierarchy of these so I could secure my DB with best practices. Should I rather configure access at Azure Portal or at the Database? Which one takes precedence in case of different authorizations? How about auditing of security changes? Not really trying to solve an engineering problem as much as wanting to be informed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your comment, please look at this Azure SQL database document: [An overview of Azure SQL Database security capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-security-overview):

This article outlines the basics of securing the data tier of an application using Azure SQL Database. The security strategy described follows the layered defense-in-depth approach as shown in the picture below, and moves from the outside in:

[image]

It will help you learn from the Azure SQL database security. To know more about the access control and Authorization.

Azure also gives the security best practices to teach you how to use these them.

Reference: [Azure SQL Database security best practices playbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-security-best-practice). This document provides guidance on how to solve common security requirements for new or existing applications using Azure SQL Database.

Hope this helps.